# How to convert PK format data to excel in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

`PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x009bwR\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[Content_Types].xml�…\n\x00\x00xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPK`

This is the response from an API I'm trying to download an excel
It is working in postman
Please suggest a code to download excel from this format

I tried all blob creating urls

```
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: '' });

const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: That looks to be a .zip file -- and .xlsx files are .zip files, so that's probably ok, you just need to save it into a file.

Comment: I tried saving as both zip and xlsx both are coruppted and not able to open by respective apps