Corrupted Excel File on download Excel file feature in vue js
I'm currently developing a feature that enables users to download an Excel file through an endpoint. However, when I implemented it, the downloaded Excel file appears corrupted. Interestingly, when I used the same cURL command in Postman, the file downloaded perfectly and rendered without any issues.
I've included my code below:
async downloadExcel() {
    try {
        const response = await InteractionService.getDiscussionExport({key: '5', exportType: 'Excel'});

        console.log('response', response);

        // Create Blob from Excel file data
        const blob = new Blob([response], {
            type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        });

        // Create URL and trigger download
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'csr-discussion.xlsx');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();

        // Clean up
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error downloading Excel file:', error);
    }
}

    public static async getDiscussionExport({
key,
afterId,
hideCsrData = true,
exportType = 'Word',
}: {
key: string,

afterId?: number,

hidexyzData?: boolean,

exportType?: 'Word' | 'Excel',
}): Promise<any> {
        const result = await __request({
            method: 'GET',
            path: `xxxx`,
            query: {
                'afterId': afterId,
                'hidexyzData': hidexyzData,
                'exportType': exportType,
            },
            errors: {
                403: `Error: Forbidden`,
                422: `Error: Unprocessable Entity`,
            }

        });
        return result.body;
    }

I've created a method to generate the Blob file, which is used to download the XLSX file. The expectation is that the downloaded file should open properly in Excel, just as it did when downloaded via Postman using the same cURL command and response

Is the response a valid excel file?

'PK' is
the response which I got
@DanielA.White

so that does sound like a zip file - why not download the file manually and see if that opens

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77843961/how-to-convert-pk-format-data-to-excel-in-javascript/78255778?noredirect=1#comment137962239_78255778 @DanielA.White this is the reference question which is same as mine

@DanielA.White the file opens perfectly when I triggered same cUrl bash through postman and then download the file through the same

It's unclear how you determined it works correctly with Postman. InteractionService.getDiscussionExport belongs to the app and is the first thing to blame. The question is irrelevant to Vue as it doesn't affect the way it works

@EstusFlask for postman, I've used the same cUrl Bash of the  triggered API in Browser and after that I've downloaded  the file through  the save button provided by the postman and yes this question is mainly related to  JS and downloading the file through Blob

Which api? Does getDiscussionExport do a request? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , because there's nothing to work with regarding JS. It's unknown what's getDiscussionExport. Code you posted could be workable

@EstusFlask getDiscussionExport is the end-point which gives response of  a binary archived as a zip (pk) , here when I trigger api (alias getDiscussionExport as in service)  through postman, it returns the perfect excel file but when I tried the same through the feature I made (code is mentioned in the description) the excel file get corrupted

@DanielA.White an XLSX file is essentially a ZIP archive

@EstusFlask I've attached code of the service in the description for the refrence

It's unknown if the service is working correctly. What is __request? You have to treat binary data carefully. If it's fetch() then it should use blob or arrayBuffer. I expect a problem with encoding. Did you try to do a binary compare of downloaded files? This could give some hint about what's going on

@DarkBee I know that

Didn't sound like that to me - "so that does sound like a zip file"
